# painting inside widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I created a very simple GUI that has a push button and a "Graphics View" widget from Display Widgets. On pushing the button I want a line to be drawn across the "Graphics View" widget. I have changed the name of the "Graphics View" widget to gv by right-clicking the widget in design view and then selecting change objectName. I am not able to understand how should the line be drawn. I read various texts on Qt that provided information about QPainter, PaintEvent etc. But I got more confused.

Kindly help me with this. A small sample code shall be really helpful for me as I am new to Qt.

Answer (score 4):

A QGraphicsView is meant for displaying instances of QGraphicsItem that are managed by a component called QGraphicsScene. In your case, you'd create a [QGraphicsLineItem](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgraphicslineitem.html) and add it to the scene, or directly create it as an item of the scene by calling the [addLine](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgraphicsscene.html#addLine) member function of your QGraphicsScene instance.

All drawing will be done by Qt itself, assuming that you did connect your graphics view and scene properly. Be sure to read [The Graphics View Framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/graphicsview.html), which gives you an overview over how these components work.

You will find code examples of how to manage and display a scene using the graphics view framework here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/examples-graphicsview.html

Answer (score 3):

You can paint into a QPainter

Either override the paintevent and draw there

```
void MyDisplayWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter p(this);   
    p.setPen(Qt::green);

    p.drawText(10,10,"hello");

}
```

Or draw into a QImage and display that

```
QImage image = QImage(size);
QPainter p(&image);
p.drawText(10,10,"hello");
// draw or save QImage
```

You can even use the same draw function taking a QPainter * to draw either direct to the screen or to an image.

Comment: I created a widget MyDisplayWidget. But I have designed a form mainwindow.ui using Qt's drag-n-drop facility. How do I include this new widget in that gui ?

Comment: There is a lot of coding to be done to be able to use custom widgets in Qt's designer application. If you want to use your custom widget in your mainwindow, use the designer application to put a place holder widget (or frame) and then in the code for your main window, create an instance of your custom widget and add it to the place holder.

Comment: @nishant-4545:  Promoted widgets are a quick way to get the job done.  See http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: @Arnold Spence - sorry this wasn't a very good example for just drawing a line on a button. I'm using it to draw video into a GLWidget

Comment: No worries. I was just trying to fill in some additional info for the OP after he mentioned he was using Qt's Designer :)

Answer (score -1):

first you must knew some information about QPainter to have benefit of it.

QPainter provides highly optimized functions to do most of the drawing GUI programs require. It can draw everything from simple graphical primitives (represented by the QPoint, QLine, QRect, QRegion and QPolygon classes) to complex shapes like vector paths .and we use it to draw on paint devices
then render it to view,and we have alot of qpaint devices like : QWidget, QImage, QPixmap, QPicture, QPrinter, and QOpenGLPaintDevice you can use any one of them depending on your requirements then create QGraphic scene  and add you paint device as qgraphic scene item to be shown in qgraphic view.

here is simple code:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene=new QGraphicsScene(this); //allocate your scene to your main widget
    view=new QGraphicsView(scene,this);//here is your view
    pixmap=new QPixmap(QSize(700,700));// paint device
    view->resize(700,700);

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    painter=new QPainter;// create your painter
    painter->begin(pixmap);//add painter to your paint device

    painter->fillRect(0,0,300,300,Qt::red);//draw rect
    painter->setPen(Qt::yellow);
    painter->drawLine(0,0,700,700);//draw line
    painter->end();
    scene->addPixmap(*pixmap);// add your paint device to your scene
    view->show();//then show your view

}
```